# Cannot identify image file al generar una imagen con pillow

Tags: python, pillow

Estoy creando un bot para discord que genera imágenes. El problema es que no me genera la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo mi código:

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre):
    response = requests.get(f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=" +Nombre+ "&searchLanguage=es")
    imagen = response.json()['data'][0]['images']['icon']
    url_imagen = f"{imagen}"
    nombre_local_imagen = "cosmetico.png"
    imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
    with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(imagen)
        img2 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        img1 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("BurbankBigCondensed-Black.otf", 60)

        draw.text((75, 10), f"IKÓNIKO", font=font, fill="white")  

        img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2) 
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('cosmetico.png'))
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
bot.run('')
```

Comment: El snippet solo es para código html, css y JS

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo de lo que puede contener la variable nombre por favor?

Comment: el comando es: !item saxofonista y deberia de volverme está imagen: https://i.imgur.com/h61CAKG.png pero no lo hace y me da error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Aclaraciones

Debido a varios motivos, no pude trabajar con el código original.
Escribí un código nuevo a partir del tuyo y lo fui modificando hasta conseguir algo.

Este es el código del que partí:

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre):
    # este es el link de uno de los iconos más nuevos a la fecha de esta respuesta
    url_imagen = f"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_827_antiquepal_bl5er/icon.png" 
    nombre_local_imagen = "cosmetico.png"
    imagen = requests.get(url_imagen).content
    with open(nombre_local_imagen, 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(imagen)
        img2 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        img1 = Image.open(r"cosmetico.png") 
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial", 60)

        draw.text((75, 10), f"IKÓNIKO", font=font, fill="white")  

        img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2) 
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('cosmetico.png'))
        img1.save("cosmetico.png")
bot.run("el token de un bot de prueba")
```

#### Propuesta

En lugar de solucionar tu problema, te propongo un código alternativo. Ni siquiera necesitas guardar un solo archivo gracias al modulo io.

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

import io

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre):
    url_imagen = f"https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/bid_827_antiquepal_bl5er/icon.png"

    # cargo la imagen desde la memoria
    img1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url_imagen).content))

    # creo una segunda imagen copiando la original
    img2 = img1.copy()

    # Cargo la fuente. Como no tengo la fuente que usas, uso arial.
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial", 60)

    # cargo la clase que me permitirá dibujar en la segunda imagen y dibujo la palabra IKÓNIKO.
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
    draw.text((75, 10), f"IKÓNIKO", font=font, fill="white")


    # pego la segunda imagen en la primera usando de mascara la segunda
    img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2)

    # guardamos la imagen en un objeto io.BytesIo y movemos el cursor al principio con seek(0)
    # posteriormente enviamos la imagen
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)

        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='image.png'))
        
bot.run('El token de mi bot de prueba')
```

Yo creo que a partir de este código podrás recrear tu código para que funcione acorde a lo que buscas.

Este es el resultado en Discord:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Aplicando mi código a lo que necesitas (no está probado si funciona)

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

import io

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help

@bot.command()
async def item(ctx, *, Nombre):
    response = requests.get(f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=" +Nombre+ "&searchLanguage=es")
    url_imagen = response.json()['data'][0]['images']['icon']

    # cargo la imagen desde la memoria
    img1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url_imagen).content))

    # creo una segunda imagen copiando la original
    img2 = img1.copy()

    # Cargo la fuente. Como no tengo la fuente que usas, uso arial.
    font = ImageFont.truetype("BurbankBigCondensed-Black.otf", 60)

    # cargo la clase que me permitirá dibujar en la segunda imagen y dibujo la palabra IKÓNIKO.
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
    draw.text((75, 10), f"IKÓNIKO", font=font, fill="white")


    # pego la segunda imagen en la primera usando de mascara la segunda
    img1.paste(img2,(0,0), mask = img2)

    # guardamos la imagen en un objeto io.BytesIo y movemos el cursor al principio con seek(0)
    # posteriormente enviamos la imagen
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)

        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='image.png'))
    
bot.run('El token de mi bot de prueba')
```

#### Creditos

Para lograr este código utilicé las siguientes respuestas de stackoverflow en ingles:

- [Send Pillow image on Discord without saving the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63210850/12913664)
- [Open PIL image from byte file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908899/12913664)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo resuelto ✔

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, podrías apoyarme aceptandola c: